# Merge two string and produce the lexicographical smallest merged string

Tags: string, algorithm, greedy

I was solving a problem when I encountered a rather simple sub problem. Given two string `S1` and `S2`,  `merge(S1,S2)` denotes any string that's obtained by interspersing the two strings `S1` and `S2`, maintaining the order of characters in both such that the resultant string is lexicographically smallest.

**Example**

```
S1 = abad
S2 = bbde
merge(S1, S2) = ababbdde
```

Now, i tried to solve the problem by applying a greedy technique starting from the first element of both the string and then looking for the smallest element and adding it to the result. But, soon I found out that this doesn't always lead to the optimal solution. The code looked something like below.

```
int n = a.size(), m = b.size();
int i =0, j=0, k=0; char array[n+m];
for(; i< n && j<n;) {
    if(a[i] < b[j]) {
        array[k] = a[i];
        ++i;
    }
    else {
        array[k] = b[j];
        ++j;
    }
    ++k;
}

while(i<n) {
    array[k] = a[i];
    ++i;
    ++k;
}
while(j<m) {

    array[k] = b[j];
    ++j;
    ++k;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n+m; ++i) {
     cout<<array[i];
}
cout<<endl;
```

I thought of traversing it backwards and choosing the largest character and started adding it from behind. With the limited testing I performed this looked good.

```
int n = a.size(), m = b.size();
int i =n-1, j=m-1, k=n+m-1; char array[n+m];
for(; i>=0  && j>=0;) {
    if(a[i] > b[j]) {
        array[k] = a[i];
        --i;
    }
    else {
        array[k] = b[j];
        --j;
    }
    --k;
}
while(i>=0) {
    array[k] = a[i];
    --i;
    --k;
}
while(j>=0) {
    array[k] = b[j];
    --j;
    --k;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n + m; ++i) {
    cout<<array[i];
}
cout<<endl;
```

But, I'm unsure if this will always give the optimal solution always.

Is this solution correct in the first place and if yes can someone give me a slight proof as to why this produces the optimal solution always too.

Comment: I have a feeling that your greedy algorithm is almost correct and it should start working if you fork your search when you see equal letters in both strings.

Answer (score 1):

The greedy approach works, however,

```
if(a[i] < b[j]) {
        array[k] = a[i];
        ++i;
    }
    else {
        array[k] = b[j];
        ++j;
    }
```

this part is incorrect because when `a[i] == b[j]` you can't simply assign `b[j]` to `array[k]`.

Instead, you need to compare the substring `a[i:]` and `b[j:]` when `a[i] == b[j]`, and you can just operate on the `std::string` itself:

```
if(s1[i] < s2[j]) 
{
    array[k] = s1[i];
    ++i;
}
else if (s1[i] == s2[j] && s1.substr(i) < s2.substr(j))
{
    array[k] = s1[i];
    ++i;
}
else 
{
    array[k] = s2[j];
    ++j;
}
```

The time complexity would be quadratic (`O(n^2)`) since `substr` operation takes `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's full solution based on my comment earlier.

```
import string
import random

global brute_force_lowest
global almost_greedy_lowest

global brute_force_calls
global almost_greedy_calls

def brute_force(p, a, b):
  global brute_force_lowest
  global brute_force_calls

  brute_force_calls += 1

  if len(a) > 0: brute_force(p + a[0], a[1:], b)
  if len(b) > 0: brute_force(p + b[0], a, b[1:])

  if len(a) == 0 and len(b) == 0:
    if p < brute_force_lowest: brute_force_lowest = p


def almost_greedy(p, a, b):
  global almost_greedy_lowest
  global almost_greedy_calls

  almost_greedy_calls += 1

  if len(a) == 0 and len(b) == 0:
    if p < almost_greedy_lowest: almost_greedy_lowest = p
  elif len(b) == 0:
    almost_greedy(p + a, '', '')
  elif len(a) == 0:
    almost_greedy(p + b, '', '')
  elif a[0] < b[0]:
    almost_greedy(p + a[0], a[1:], b)
  elif a[0] > b[0]:
    almost_greedy(p + b[0], a, b[1:])
  else:
    almost_greedy(p + a[0], a[1:], b)
    almost_greedy(p + b[0], a, b[1:])


for j in range(10000):
  a = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(2, 10)))
  b = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(2, 10)))
  brute_force_lowest = a + b
  brute_force_calls = 0
  brute_force('', a, b)
  almost_greedy_calls = 0
  almost_greedy_lowest = a + b
  almost_greedy('', a, b)
  print('%s, %s -> %s vs. %s (%.3f)' % (a, b, brute_force_lowest, almost_greedy_lowest, float(almost_greedy_calls) / brute_force_calls))
  if almost_greedy_lowest != brute_force_lowest: print 'ERROR'
```

[image]
One interesting statistic is that this algorithm works about ten times faster then brute force algorithm on average if we limit alphabet to 'ab'.

UPDATE Some optimizations:

```
def prefix_length(a):
  for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != a[0]: return i
  return len(a)

def almost_greedy(p, a, b):
  global almost_greedy_lowest
  global almost_greedy_calls

  almost_greedy_calls += 1

  if p > almost_greedy_lowest: return

  if len(a) == 0 and len(b) == 0:
    if p < almost_greedy_lowest: almost_greedy_lowest = p
  elif len(b) == 0:
    almost_greedy(p + a, '', '')
  elif len(a) == 0:
    almost_greedy(p + b, '', '')
  elif a[0] < b[0]:
    almost_greedy(p + a[0], a[1:], b)
  elif a[0] > b[0]:
    almost_greedy(p + b[0], a, b[1:])
  else:
    la = prefix_length(a)
    almost_greedy(p + a[0] * la, a[la:], b)
    lb = prefix_length(b)
    almost_greedy(p + b[0] * lb, a, b[lb:])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The python code is pretty hard for me to comprehend. I'll accept this as the answer as soon I wrap my head around the code.

Comment: @thebenman Still wrapping your head around it?

Answer (score -1):

Greedy will solve the problem. to solve this problem you will have to visit both string for sure.

In your code you are missing at one place i.e. your first for loop `if(a[i] < b[j])` it should be `if(a[i] <= b[j])`. 
check the code [here](http://ideone.com/elfKSy)

Comment: This will not work for string "cccc" & "ccccaaaa" output should be "ccccaaaacccc" but you program is giving "ccccccccaaaa"

Comment: just reverse the order of input. you can swap between a and b depending upon who is lexicographical smaller and having length smaller.

Comment: If we switch a and b input strings the code fails to give the optimal solution. I don't think that this change will cover all scenarios. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @thebenman In any case you will have to visit both the string. then how does it matter ? space complexity will O(m+n) and time will O(n). correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Cereal_Killer If a=bbde and b=bbde result is ababbdde(which the optimal merge). But if we were to switch a and b then we get abbbadde(not the optimal solution). What happens with the change you mentioned is that in case a[i] == b[j] then we pick a[i] instead of b[j]. But this doesn't guarantee the optimal solution ALWAYS. This should work about 50% percent of the time if I am not wrong. Without the equality symbol what was happening is that in case of a[i] == b[j] it was picking up b[j] from the else part. Either way space and time complexity remain the same.

Comment: @thebenmen your example isn't clear "If a=bbde and b=bbde result is ababbdde(which the optimal merge)"  both are same string, you will always get the same result. tell me one thing.. if both are character are same you can choose any of it. you will always end up at optimal solution. Please give me a example where it will fail. The example you have given is working fine with my code. I tested it. PS If I understood your problem correctly then you can not modify string "a" and string "b" to get optimal lexicographical string. http://ideone.com/AKMaic

Comment: @Cereal_Killer Sorry, that was a typo. Check this http://ideone.com/8FWU9B. Also, if two characters are same picking any one will ALWAYS NOT give you the optimal solution. Check Manvel's answer below where he suggests to fork the so far merged string  when similar characters are encountered. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score -1):

Greedy will not give the correct solution and forking will increase the time complexity of the algorithm as you would have to continually revisit the substring that was the same in both strings. Instead, use a dequeue to store the characters that are common, and compare the next char to be chosen from either the deque, or the first string, or the second string

Look at the solution below (replace ints with char from the string, and switch the comparatror signs)

> ```
> def maxNumber(self, nums1, nums2):
>     """
>     :type nums1: List[int]
>     :type nums2: List[int]
>     :type k: int
>     :rtype: List[int]
>     """
>     d = deque()
>     arr = []
>     i, j = 0, 0
>     while i < len(nums1) and j < len(nums2):
>         if len(d) and d[0] > nums1[i] and d[0] > nums2[j]:
>             arr.append(d.popleft())
>         else:
>             if nums1[i] > nums2[j]:
>                 arr.append(nums1[i])
>                 i += 1
>             elif nums1[i] < nums2[j]:
>                 arr.append(nums2[j])
>                 j += 1
>             else:
>                 arr.append(nums1[i])
>                 d.append(nums2[j])
>                 i += 1
>                 j += 1
>     while i < len(nums1):
>         if len(d) and d[0] > nums1[i]:
>             arr.append(d.popleft())
>         else:
>             arr.append(nums1[i])
>             i += 1
>     while j < len(nums2):
>         if len(d) and d[0] > nums2[j]:
>             arr.append(d.popleft())
>         else:
>             arr.append(nums2[j])
>             j += 1
>     while len(d):
>         arr.append(d.popleft())
>     return arr
> ```